# Convert day fraction and year to Panda Python Datatime

Tags: python, pandas

I need help seem to convert

```
    Year    DayFraction
1   1979    2.47
2   1979    2.83
3   1979    2.96
```

to the format I need. I'm trying to have it in the `2019/02/02 8:30:00` format but in pandas. If I titled this wrong please let me know. I am still new to this.

The issue was resolved by (Thank you all for helping):

for i in np.arange(len(Year)): temptime = [] for i in np.arange(len(Year)): temp = pd.to_datetime(Year[i], format = '%Y') + pd.Timedelta(days= DayF[i]-2) temptime = np.append([temptime], temp)

Comment: Can you share what the correctly formatted date would be for one of the examples?

Comment: what is the `max` of DayFraction column ?

Comment: I don't know what a `'DayFraction'` is.  And I don't know what a year of `1979` and a `'DayFraction'` of `2.47` should resolve to.  You can help potential answerers out by adhering to [mcve].

Comment: @ansev the max is 366.92084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it helps. You can try this,

```py
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Year': [1979, 1979, 1979],
    'DayFraction': [2.47, 2.83, 2.96]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['new_date'] = (df
   .apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['Year'], format='%Y') + 
   timedelta(days=x['DayFraction']), 
   axis=1))

print(df)

   Year  DayFraction            new_date
0  1979         2.47 1979-01-03 11:16:48
1  1979         2.83 1979-01-03 19:55:12
2  1979         2.96 1979-01-03 23:02:24
```

If you got `TypeError: 'float' object is unsliceable` error,

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y')
df['DayFraction'] = df['DayFraction'].apply(lambda x: timedelta(days=x))
df['new_date'] = df['DayFraction'] + df['Year']
```

If these are lists,

```
Year = [1979, 1979, 1979]
DayF = [2.47, 2.83, 2.96]

new_dates = []

for y, d in zip(Year, DayF):
    new = pd.to_datetime(y, format='%Y') + pd.Timedelta(days=d)
    new_dates.append(new)

print(new_dates)

[Timestamp('1979-01-03 11:16:48'), Timestamp('1979-01-03 19:55:12'), Timestamp('1979-01-03 23:02:24')]
```

Comment: When applying this it gives me the error of ('DayF', 'occurred at index 0') were DayF is my Day of Fraction data

Comment: Have you forgotten to include `axis=1`?

Comment: no I have this
data = {
    'Year',
    'DayFm'
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def find_new_date(row):
    """
    return: first day of year (year) + total seconds (diff) 
    """
    diff = 24 * 60 * 60 * row['DayFm']
    year = datetime(year=int(row['Year']), month=1, day=1)
    return year + timedelta(seconds=diff)

df['new_date'] = df.apply(find_new_date, axis=1)

Comment: That's my old answer. I edited my answer. Can you check again please?

Comment: data = {
   Bsub['Year'],
   Bsub['DayFraction']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['new_date'] = (df
   .apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['Year'], format='%Y') + 
   timedelta(days=x['DayFraction']), 
   axis=1))

Comment: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Can I know which version of python you are using?

Comment: The most recent version. 3.8 (Thank you for helping btw)

Comment: I added another way to my answer. Can you try it?

Comment: We got something to work! for i in np.arange(len(Year)):
    temptime = []
for i in np.arange(len(Year)):
    temp = pd.to_datetime(Year[i], format = '%Y') + pd.Timedelta(days= DayF[i]-2)
    temptime = np.append([temptime], temp)

Comment: I didn't know these were list. :) Congrats!

Comment: I added another way for lists @WoodyTheCoder :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what types are your columns, but I assumed that they were ints/floats.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np

#creating DataFrame
d = {'Year': [1979]*3, 'DayFraction': np.array([2.47, 2.83, 2.96])}
df  = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#converting types
df['Year'] = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp(str(i)) for i in df['Year']])
df['DayFraction'] = pd.Series([timedelta(days=i) for i in df['DayFraction']])

#adding the dates
df['NewFormat'] = df['Year'] + df['DayFraction']

#See result
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
df["Date"]=pd.to_timedelta(
    df["DayFraction"].sub(1), unit="d"
).add(
    pd.to_datetime(df["Year"], format="%Y")
)
```

Output:

```py
   Year  DayFraction                Date
0  1979         2.47 1979-01-02 11:16:48
1  1979         2.83 1979-01-02 19:55:12
2  1979         2.96 1979-01-02 23:02:24
```

One note - since you want `2.47` to be during second day of the year - we need to subtract `1` (unless you want it to be 3rd - then remove `.sub(1)`), because year starts 1st January, not 0 January.